# Google AdSense in Salesforce Community

Tags: napili

I am trying to add google AdSense in community, Napili template. Has anyone tried this before. Please do help.

Google Adsense gives a script file and tells to add them below the  markup in community. But with the last release, script file was not possible to be added in the head markup of community builder. So i wanted to know if anyone else has tried with some work around.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: please share what you have attempted, link documentation and point out where you are stuck as indicated in [ask] . This will facilitate others into helping you.

Comment: update the question so everything is clear please. thanks!